# Spliting data set that didn't come from same source

Tags: classification, dataset, cart

I have a data set consisting of features extracted from audio files of individuals with parkinson's disease. 
In this set, the training set features were extracted approximately 40 individuals, each with 20+ different recorded sounds ranging from prolonged letter pronunciation to full sentences.
For the test set, there are ONLY diseased individuals, and the features were extracted only from samples consisting of sustained vowels "a" and "e".

I'm trying to model a classification tree from these data sets and I'm a big concerned about the test sample containing only positive samples. One idea I had was to take some random negative samples from the training data and add them to the test data and modeling a tree from this modified set pair. I'm not sure entirely that would be a good idea, I am worried that because the test set was extracted from audio samples that were made by a more restricted process that this will change the nature of the set entirely.

Would modifying the set in that way have any negative impact ?

The set I'm using is from http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Parkinson+Speech+Dataset+with++Multiple+Types+of+Sound+Recordings

Comment: Hi there and welcome. As long as you do not train on the negative samples, but select them randomly and immediately put them in the test set; you should be fine.

Comment: When you say negative samples, you mean that I don't use the same samples ,that I add to the test set, in the training set?

Comment: That's indeed a different way of saying the same. What you should avoid is: training on sample $i$, $(x_i, y_i)$, and validating/testing on that same sample $i$ as well, because the result of such a test will be optimistically biased (sometimes severely). The whole idea of using a test set is getting rid of such optimism bias.

Comment: How were the original training/test sets generated? Would it make sense to combine them and randomly sample from them to generate new test/training sets, with the proportions you want, mixing the two? It seems to me that the training data should come from the same general population as the test data, and just moving some observations from training to test doesn't really accomplish that (i.e., if I'm reading the description right, you'd be training on a dataset that has significant differences from, and may not generalize well to, the test set)

Comment: The sets come from the same population, the only thing is that for the training set, every individual had to do 20 recordings of different sounds, but for the test set the only unhealthy individuals were used and they each had only 6 samples, 3 of prolonged "a" pronunciation and 3 from prolonged "e". So in my perception the test set is more limited in it's variation

Comment: What exactly are you trying to classify with your model? Healthy vs. Unhealthy? And in an imagined future application, would individuals be recording all 20 different sounds, or just the "a" and "e" sounds? If all imagined future data would center on the "a" and "e" sounds, it doesn't seem like the other sounds will be of much value in training your model.

If you're trying to classify healthy vs. unhealthy, it might be useful to get a sense of how often the model misclassifies one vs. the other. In which case, again, generating new training/test sets from the overall dataset seems useful.

Comment: I'm attempting to classify healthy  vs unhealthy individuals. I am only recreating an experiment I found so I have not  much input on how the application would function, I imagine that the idea would be the individuals would only record the "a" and the "e" sounds though, more convenient than having them do 20+ recordings